# Pathlib mkdir raises FileExistsError despite the file not actually existing

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, filesystems

I'm trying to create a directory in python

```
data_path = Path("~/.local/share/mark_py")
data_path.mkdir()
```

For some reason this raises a *FileExistsError* but neither a file nor a directory by that name exists. I tried changing the name from "mark_py" to other names, and what happens is that it runs without raising any error the first time, but it doesn't actually create anything since I can't find the actual directory, and when I run it again it raises "FileExistsError"

This is on an **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS** running **Python 3.8.10**. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out pathlib doesn't automatically expand the tilde, you need to call *Path.expanduser()" for that. So i was creating directories in the literal "~" directory.